# sqlalchemy proper query construction

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Really new sqlalchemy user here with what is probably a basic question, but for the life of me I can't figure out the proper way to query my data.  Here is my class.

```
class Reading(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'reading'

rid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
uid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.uid'))
sid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sensor.sid'))
readingTimestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime())
readingLightValue = db.Column(db.Integer)
readingLightStatus = db.Column(db.String(6))
readingTemp1 = db.Column(db.Float)
readingTemp2 = db.Column(db.Float)
readingHumidity = db.Column(db.Float)
```

Writing data is working fine, now if I try to create a query like so.

```
result = db.session.query(Reading).order_by(Reading.readingTimestamp.desc()).limit(50)
```

I get a query object as you would expect,

```
In [36]: result.all()
Out[36]: 
[<app.account.models.Reading at 0x2b85ad0>,
<app.account.models.Reading at 0x2b85490>,
<app.account.models.Reading at 0x2b85250>,
```

but I can't figure out how to access attributes of the model.  I want to take these readings and render them out back as a table.

Thanks for setting me straight! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a list and the attributes become the attributes of the object. You'd probably want to do something like this:

```
for res in result.all():
     # do something with the id
     do_something(res.id)
```

Each `res` is an instance of your model.